# Error: ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT & ERR! syscall spawn bash

Tags: reactjs, bash, npm, next.js

I am getting errors while creating a new react or next app in my system. Tried adding path "C:\Windows\System32" and also other multiple troubleshooting but the error still persists.

node v16.13.2
npm  v8.4.0
getting the below error messages:

```
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Sailesh Jalan\Downloads\Development\Master Projects\ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\core-js
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent


the error log file shows below error:
6466 verbose stack Error: spawn bash ENOENT
6466 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
6466 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
6466 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
6467 verbose pkgid core-js@3.20.3
6468 verbose cwd C:\Users\Sailesh Jalan\Downloads\Development\Master Projects\ReactJS\my-app
6469 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
6470 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Sailesh Jalan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--no-audit" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts" "cra-template"
6471 verbose node v16.13.2
6472 verbose npm  v8.4.0
6473 error code ENOENT
6474 error syscall spawn bash
6475 error path C:\Users\Sailesh Jalan\Downloads\Development\Master Projects\ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\core-js
6476 error errno -4058
6477 error enoent spawn bash ENOENT
6478 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
6478 error enoent
6479 verbose exit -4058
```

Comment: When you say "other multiple troubleshooting," it would help to know what those are.  In any case... line 6475 of the error output seems to indicate a missing `node_modules` file rather than a missing Node executable.  You could try doing fresh `npm install` (or equivalent for your package management system) in your project to make sure all dependencies are present.

Answer (score 0):

Try same command using PowerShell with elevated privileges.